# can't receive GRE packets on a raw socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am trying to write a program which will receive GRE over IPv4 packets.

This is my python code:

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_GRE
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_GRE)

msgAndAddress = s.recvfrom(1024)

print("got message");
```

I am running the program and then another program which sends a GRE packet in the same machine over a veth pair. This is the result of tcpdump on the receiving side of the veth when sending the packet:

```
22:00:07.250726 da:1d:20:cc:b1:5f > 2a:59:3c:6f:14:9c, IPv4, length 176: (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 42963, offset 0, flags [DF], proto GRE (47), length 162)
    10.254.1.6 > 10.254.3.0: GREv0, Flags [key present], key=0x96040000, proto TEB (0x6558), length 142
    84:40:76:00:00:01 > 55:01:02:00:01:00, IPv4, length 134: (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 1, offset 0, flags [none], proto Options (0), length 20)
    1.2.2.1 > 1.2.2.2:  ip-proto-0 0
```

but the python code doesn't print anything. I also tried binding the socket to a specific ip address or interface and it didn't help.

Comment: `s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_GRE)` will raise a PermissionError exception unless the program is run as superuser.

Comment: I am running as a superuser, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was solved when I moved the other side of the veth to a new network namespace.